# Finding eigenvector only knowing others eigenvectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The matrix $A \in M_3(\mathbb{R})$ satisfy $A^t=A$ and $(1,2,1), (-1,1,0)$ are eigenvectors of $A$. Which vector is also an eigenvector of $A$?
Alternatives: $(0,0,1)$; $(1,1,-3)$; $(1,1,3)$; *There is no other eigenvector*.

The problem with this exercise is that I don't know the matrix $A$, and I don't have any eigenvalue to start with. I can get a matrix with less variables using $A = A^t$, but there's still 6 variables. Any tips or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: There is some sloppiness in the language here. Of course there are more eigenvectors. In fact, there is an infinite amount of them. For instance, for every nonzero $\lambda$, $\lambda (1, 2, 1)$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: The question only makes sense if the eigenvalues are distinct. Counter-example: if  $A = 0$ every vector is an eigenvector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $A$ is symmetric, the eigenvectors (for distinct eigenvalues) are orthogonal.

So, find which of the vectors is orthogonal to the first two.

> (1,1,-3) is.

Comment: I think I need to rethink it.  I'm leaning towards $(1,1,-3)$ because it's orthogonal to both.  Will edit.

Comment: The other two could be eigenvectors. If so, the matrix would have to be a multiple of the identity, but I don’t see anything in the problem statement that would preclude this.

Comment: @amd true.   Good catch.

Comment: @amd the orthogonal one _must_ be an eigenvector though, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Yeah the problem could probably have been better stated as "which vector is also *necessarily* an eigenvector"

Comment: @PaulSinclair I'd doesn't have three distinct eigenvalues,  because the first two eigenvectors aren't orthogonal.

Comment: You're right - I didn't notice that, and misinterpreted the "No other eigenvector" comment as a general condition, when instead it was a 4th choice to be selected.

Comment: Right you are.   @PaulSinclair

Comment: Yes, the vector orthogonal to both of the given eigenvectors must be an eigenvector one way or the other.

Comment: If the $(1,2,1),(−1,1,0)$ are not orthogonal, one of them is not part of the basis, right? The "spectral theorem" says that given a symmetric matrix, there should be an orthonormal basis. So why the answer should be orthogonal to a vector that is not part of the basis?

Comment: For a symmetric matrix,  eigenvectors corresponding to _different_ eigenvalues are orthogonal.   If on the other hand the eigenvalues are all the same, then the matrix is a multiple of the identity, and everything is an eigenvector (for that eigenvalue).

Answer (score 5):

Hint: the condition $A^t = A$ allows you to use the spectral theorem.

> Hint: Specifically, the spectral theorem implies there is an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: That is correct, but unless the eigenvalues are distinct the theorem does not say that *no other vectors* except for the basis vectors are eigenvectors.

Comment: @PaulSinclair No, I think "no other eigenvector" is a possible "choice" for this multiple choice question.

Comment: @angryavian - you are correct. As Chris Custer pointed out below his answer, the two eigenvectors given are not orthogonal. Therefore their eigenvalues have to be the same. I mis-interpreted the problem.